# Foreign Key on Code First Migration That Shouldn't Be There

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have 2 models currently that I need to run a migration for into a new database, and I'm not getting the structure that I'm expecting. I apologize if this is an easy answer, I'm fairly new to Code First with Entity Framework.

First I have a `User` object. This just should have a `UserID` for a Primary Key, and then some fields to fill in.

```
public class User : CustomDataEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I have an `Event` object. This should have an `EventID` as a Primary Key, and then I'm trying to have a ForeignKey'd `HostUser`, as well as a list of users who are registered for the event, stored in the `RegisteredUsers` table.

```
public class Event : CustomDataEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("HostUser")]
    public int HostUserID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RegisteredUsers")]
    public ICollection<int> RegisteredUserIDs { get; set; }
    public virtual User HostUser { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> RegisteredUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Based off of this, I would expect to have a database structure with `User` and `Event` tables, with a foreign keyed column in `dbo.Event` to the `User` table (for the foreign keyed HostUserID), and a lookup table that maps a list of Users to an Event (for the list of RegisteredUsers).

The issue is that when I create a migration based off of this structure, I get the following CreateTable methods for the `Up()` part.

```
public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Event",
            c => new
                {
                    EventID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    HostUserID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Description = c.String(nullable: false),
                    NumberOfUsers = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    StartDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    EndDate = c.DateTime(),
                    CreatedAt = c.DateTimeOffset(precision: 7,
                        annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues>
                        {
                            { 
                                "ServiceTableColumn",
                                new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue: "CreatedAt")
                            },
                        }),
                    Deleted = c.Boolean(nullable: false,
                        annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues>
                        {
                            { 
                                "ServiceTableColumn",
                                new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue: "Deleted")
                            },
                        }),
                    Id = c.String(
                        annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues>
                        {
                            { 
                                "ServiceTableColumn",
                                new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue: "Id")
                            },
                        }),
                    UpdatedAt = c.DateTimeOffset(precision: 7,
                        annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues>
                        {
                            { 
                                "ServiceTableColumn",
                                new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue: "UpdatedAt")
                            },
                        }),
                    Version = c.Binary(
                        annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues>
                        {
                            { 
                                "ServiceTableColumn",
                                new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue: "Version")
                            },
                        }),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.EventID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.User", t => t.HostUserID, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.HostUserID);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.User",
            c => new
                {
                    UserID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Username = c.String(nullable: false),
                    Password = c.String(nullable: false),
                    Birthday = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    FirstName = c.String(nullable: false),
                    LastName = c.String(nullable: false),
                    EmailAddress = c.String(nullable: false),
                    Picture = c.Binary(),
                    CreatedAt = c.DateTimeOffset(precision: 7,
                        annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues>
                        {
                            { 
                                "ServiceTableColumn",
                                new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue: "CreatedAt")
                            },
                        }),
                    Deleted = c.Boolean(nullable: false,
                        annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues>
                        {
                            { 
                                "ServiceTableColumn",
                                new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue: "Deleted")
                            },
                        }),
                    Id = c.String(
                        annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues>
                        {
                            { 
                                "ServiceTableColumn",
                                new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue: "Id")
                            },
                        }),
                    UpdatedAt = c.DateTimeOffset(precision: 7,
                        annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues>
                        {
                            { 
                                "ServiceTableColumn",
                                new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue: "UpdatedAt")
                            },
                        }),
                    Version = c.Binary(
                        annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues>
                        {
                            { 
                                "ServiceTableColumn",
                                new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue: "Version")
                            },
                        }),
                    Event_EventID = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.UserID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Event", t => t.Event_EventID)
            .Index(t => t.Event_EventID);

    }
```

The last two lines are the ones I want to focus on

```
.ForeignKey("dbo.Event", t => t.Event_EventID)
.Index(t => t.Event_EventID);
```

This is creating a ForeignKey on the User table to the Event Table, even though I don't have the Event_EventID defined anywhere on the User model. I think that the Migration is assuming that the User will be registered for only 1 Event at a time, since I don't see any sort of lookup table to figure out which Users are registered for which Events.

I've tried messing with my `Event` model, by putting the ForeignKey property directly on the `RegisteredUsers` object, and found out that was incorrect pretty fast.

How do I force EF to recognize that I need a Many to Many relationship for Users to Events? Or am I barking up the wrong tree in assuming that's the issue?

**EDIT**

I removed the `ForeignKey` properties and setup the ICollection to each, and I still have the same error, except now I have an ADDITIONAL Column that only allows for a single user per event, and no EventUsers table.

```
public class User : CustomDataEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Event> EventsRegisteredFor { get; set; }
}

public class Event : CustomDataEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public virtual User HostUser { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> RegisteredUsers { get; set; }
}
```

and I end up with

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Event",
            c => new
                {
                    EventID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Description = c.String(nullable: false),
                    NumberOfUsers = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    StartDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    EndDate = c.DateTime(),
                    User_UserID = c.Int(),
                    HostUser_UserID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.EventID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.User", t => t.User_UserID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.User", t => t.HostUser_UserID, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.User_UserID)
            .Index(t => t.HostUser_UserID);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.User",
            c => new
                {
                    UserID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Username = c.String(nullable: false),
                    Password = c.String(nullable: false),
                    Birthday = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    FirstName = c.String(nullable: false),
                    LastName = c.String(nullable: false),
                    EmailAddress = c.String(nullable: false),
                    Picture = c.Binary(),
                    Event_EventID = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.UserID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Event", t => t.Event_EventID)
            .Index(t => t.Event_EventID);
```

**EDIT 2**
I went through and got my models down to the most base information I could use.

```
public class User : CustomDataEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
public class Event : CustomDataEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public virtual User HostUser { get; set; }
    public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

However, this structure still doesn't give me the necessary EventUsers or UserEvents table, it simply adds a single column to the database that allows for a single UserID

```
 public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Event",
            c => new
                {
                    EventID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    User_UserID = c.Int(),
                    HostUser_UserID = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.EventID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.User", t => t.User_UserID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.User", t => t.HostUser_UserID)
            .Index(t => t.User_UserID)
            .Index(t => t.HostUser_UserID);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.User",
            c => new
                {
                    UserID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Username = c.String(),
                    Event_EventID = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.UserID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Event", t => t.Event_EventID)
            .Index(t => t.Event_EventID);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Many-To-Many Relationship , just add a collection in each model:

in user model add:

public virtual ICollection Events { set; get; } // many-to-many

and in Event Model add:

public virtual ICollection Users { set; get; } // many-to-many

---

you don't need to use any other foreign keys.

the entity framework automatically creates the EventUsers Table and you cannot access this table from your dbcontext. (you don't need too access )

but if you want to access the EventUsers Table you should delete the many to many relationship from users and events, crate a new model for example EventUsers and make a one to many relation from user to eventusers and from event to eventusers.

Comment: I tried this, and I end up with the same issue, except now I ALSO have a User_UserID column in the database that only allows for 1 user per event. I'll put my code in an Edit

Answer (score 0):

in many to many relationship it will create a third table which includes primary keys of both tables e.g

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
public class Event
{
    [Key]
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

note that i used `list` of events in `user` class and same in `event` class which means a user can have many events and a event can have many users (`many to many`)
so when i add migration it will create third table name `UserEvent` which will include foreign keys of both tables.

**Edit**

you have used  `public virtual User HostUser { get; set; }`  it created one to many relationship so you are tying create only one relationship which is many to many so there is no need of `public virtual User HostUser { get; set; }`

Comment: and no need of     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] and : CustomDataEntity

Comment: Do I need "ITableData" instead of CustomDataEntity?

Comment: no you dont need to put anything dbcontext will handle it when you add models in dbset

Comment: what is the reason of adding     public virtual User HostUser { get; set; }